# ListView SelectedItem does not get sychronized

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I have following ListView and using MVVM Light

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Combinations, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Combination, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
             Style="{StaticResource UserValueStyle}" SelectionMode="Single"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button Content="{Binding Text}" FontSize="20" Height="80" Width="100" FontWeight="Bold"
                  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.OnUserValuePressed}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The property:

```
public SapInspectionUserValue Combination
    {
      get
      {
        return _combination;
      }
      set
      {
        _combination = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
      }
    }
```

The class property:

```
  public class SapInspectionUserValue
  {
    public string Combination { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
  }
```

My problem is, when I select an item(in my case, press the button) the `SelectedItem` does not get synchronized and I do not know why. Whats is wrong?

Comment: It looks ok to me. But how is RaisePropertyChanged() implemented?

Comment: When you press the button, have you confirmed that `OnUserValuePressed` isn't null, that whatever it is does implement `ICommand`, that its `Execute` method does assign a new value to `Combination`, that the new value you assign in that method to `Combination` is not null, and that the new value is an actual instance found in the `Combinations` collection? If any of those conditions isn't true, that would cause this to fail.